# @Async and Mockito issue

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, asynchronous, mockito

I have this class.

```
@Service
public class ConcurrentService{

    public Map<String, Object> createList(){
       this.asynCall();
    }

    @Async("taskExecutor")
    private Future<Map<String, Object>> asynCall(){
    .....
    return new AsyncResult<Map<String, Object>>(mapResultMap);
    }

}
```

My spring config is:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor"  mode="aspectj" />

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="50" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="300" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="30" />
</bean>
```

And My Mockito Unit test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ConcurrentServiceTest{

    @InjectMocks
    private ConcurrentService concurrentService;

    @Mock(name = "taskExecutor")
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        Assert.assertNotNull(concurrentService.createList();
    }
}
```

If I run this I obtained `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BeanFactory must be set on AnnotationAsyncExecutionAspect to access qualified executor 'taskExecutor'` from the `org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_scheduling_aspectj_AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect`

If I remove the qualifier in the annotation and just left `@Async`, this test run perfectly, but If I add the `@Async("taskExecutor")` the error comes again.

I believe Spring does not need to run as this is just Unit test, what can I do to disable aop in Mockito or what should I do to use the name "taskExecutor"

Comment: If you just omit `@EnableAsync` from your test configuration class, the `@Async` annotations will just get ignored, so everything will be called synchronously. You can then remove the `Executor` mock. This is probably the best way to be doing tests.

Comment: Im using spring3.2 so @EnableAsync does not apply, also this is mockito unit test, Spring is not running in that time, if I remove the mock  but still have Asyn with a value , error still happens.

Comment: How do you run the test? Maybe your IDE integrates somehow with Spring and does more than you suspect (just guessing)?

Comment: Interesting observation, and I believe you are pointing in some kind of right direction, Im using eclipse and intellijidea in the second IDE this works fine but not in eclise, what I am doing is using MockitJunitRunner and run as a test in eclipse, somehow IDE could be including AOP stuff, but when I run with jenkins test failed

Answer (score 0):

With `mode="aspectj"` in

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" mode="aspectj" />
```

you are using Aspectj weaving, and you needs to use `aspectj-maven-plugin` to weave aspects in compile time. For using Spring's AOP default framework with proxies in runtime, change to

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" />
```